# excel graph of 3-dimenstional data with repeating groups in two axises

Tags: excel, charts, repeat

I would like to make a line graph with 3-dimensional data where I have repeating groups in the X-axis values and legend. Please take a look at the attached picture. [image]

The graph that is included in the picture is the result of a simple line scatter with data that is under the graph. But this data uses transposed rows to column (stock). I don't want to do that. I want to keep the repeating groups as rows. Any idea how I can get based on the data on the left, the graph at the right ?

Comment: But what is your question? Is the image what you want to do, or what you have done? You need to describe both what you have done and what you want and how they differ. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed because it is not clear. Please edit it and add more details.

Comment: This task is exactly what [PivotCharts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivotchart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) are meant for.